# Validation of formik input field is not working properly in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, formik

Here I have a text field validation with Formik. On that, I have given some conditions that validate the text field, but the problem is, let's take an example: if I want to write a text, it's not able to be written, if condition is not satisfy then textfield throws an error at the time submit so how do I fix that and maintain all of the error message validation?

```
import { useFormik } from "formik";

export default function App() {
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      inputValue: ""
    },
    validate: (values) => {
      let errors = {};
      const regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_() ]+$/;
      if (!values.inputValue) {
        errors.inputValue = "Value is required";
      }
      if (values.inputValue?.length < 3) {
        errors.inputValue = "Text field must be at least 3 characters long";
      }
      if (
        values.inputValue.charAt(0) === " " ||
        values.inputValue.charAt(values.inputValue.length - 1) === " "
      ) {
        errors.inputValue = "Space is not allowed at starting and at the end";
      }
      if (!regex.test(values.inputValue)) {
        errors.inputValue = "Value should be alphanumeric";
      }
      return errors;
    },
    onSubmit: async (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
      setSubmitting(true);
      try {
        const response = await fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2", {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          }
        });
        setSubmitting(false);
        if (response.status === 200) {
          console.log("compile successfully");
        } else {
          console.log("not compiled successfully");
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
        <input
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
          value={formik.values.inputValue}
          style={{ border: formik.errors.inputValue && "2px solid red" }}
        />
        <div style={{ color: "red" }}>{formik.errors.inputValue}</div>
        <button type="submit" disable={formik.isSubmitting}>
          Click
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```